# Chrome CSS Perspective not working on all blocks

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have some strange behaviour on a webshop I am developing.
In Google Chrome one of the two divs that should be rotated remains flat. The other one is properly rotated.
Everything works fine in Firefox.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Here are the Screenshots (Chrome on the left and Firefox on the right):

[image: Chrome][image: Firefox]
Here is the relevant Html and Css code:

```
<div id="live-preview" class="live-preview portrait" style="color: rgb(192, 192, 192); font-family: helvetica;">
    <div class="bg-image" id="back" style="background-image: url(http://www.fastermaster.at//templates/diplombinderei.at/images/material/0.jpg);">
        <div class="bg-color" id="back-bg" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039);">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-image" id="spine" style="background-image: url(http://www.fastermaster.at//templates/diplombinderei.at/images/material/0.jpg);">
        <div class="bg-color" id="spine-bg" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039);">
            <span class="first-line"></span>
            <span class="second-line"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-image" id="front" style="background-image: url(http://www.fastermaster.at//templates/diplombinderei.at/images/material/0.jpg);">
        <div class="bg-color" id="front-bg" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039);">
            <span class="first-line typo-big typo-center">Just SomeText</span>
            <span class="second-line"></span>
            <span class="third-line"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.portrait #front {
right: 7;
}
.portrait #back, .portrait #front {
position: absolute;
width: 132px;
height: 214px;
}
#front {
transform: rotateY(7deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(7deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(7deg);
}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
text-decoration: none;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
display: block;
}
Inherited from div#live-preview.live-preview.portrait
Style Attribute {
color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
font-family: helvetica;
}
.live-preview {
font-family: Times;
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
perspective: 252px;
-webkit-perspective: 252px;
-ms-perspective: 252px;
perspective-origin: 50% -68%;
-webkit-perspective-origin-x: 50%;
-webkit-perspective-origin-y: -68%;
-ms-perspective-origin-x: 50%;
-ms-perspective-origin-y: -68%;
}
```

You can see the live page at http://www.fastermaster.at/konfigurator

EDIT:

I tried opening the page in Incognito mode, so that all Chrome Extensions are inactive, but the result is still the same.

Comment: Its ok on my browser.

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos
What Chrome Version are you using?

Comment: In my chrome its also displayed wrong so I'll look a bit into it now ;)

Comment: first thing I noticed is that when you inspect the element that the selection is displayed rotated correctly, which is very strange

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom Yes, I noticed that too. Even the selection of span element that is inside the div is displayed rotated, but the span itself is not.

Comment: It seems there was a bug in Chrome. I just received (automatic) update and after restart everything is fine.
New Version: 38.0.2125.101 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was a bug in Chrome. I received (automatic) update mid October and after restart everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Usually do so cross-browser transform

```
#front {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(15deg); /* For Firefox */
  -ms-transform: rotate(15deg); /* For IE */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg); /* For Safari, Chrome, iOS */
  -o-transform: rotate(15deg); /* For Opera */
}
```